# What is the grading system? (In The Groove)

Tags: in-the-groove

In The Groove is a music game, heavily based on Dance Dance Revolution. It has an entirely different scoring system based on percentage which favors your step-by-step accuracy over hitting every step inaccurately. Now onto my question.

[image: http://snag.gy/tUImS.jpg]

This as an image of my best run on the hardest song in the original ITG (Pandemonium on Expert, the only 13. ITG2 added Vertex^2 and Summer -Speedy Mix-). What the most important part of this screen is the percentage score and the 'rank' to the left of it. With 0.00%, you get an F and with 96+, the rating moves from letters to Stars. What I know is this:

- Quad Star: 100% (Every step is a Fantastic. Confirmed. Also ridiculous.)
- Tri Star: 99% (Does this require you to get nothing but Excellents and Fantastics?)
- Double Star: 98% (Again, does this require an Excellent Full Combo?)
- Star: 96% (Does not require anything other than the score. Confirmed.)
- S+: 94%
- S: 92%? (I am unsure on this one. I recall getting a 92.09 on a song and only getting S-.)
- S-: 90%

**What are the rest of the ranks?**

Answer (score 2):

Here's the full list of ranks, courtesy of [bemani wikia](http://bemani.wikia.com/wiki/In_the_groove_(game)):

4 Stars: 100%
3 Stars: 99%
2 Stars: 98%
1 Star: 96%
S+: 94%
S: 92%
S-: 89%
A+: 86%
A: 83%
A-: 80%
B+: 76%
B: 72%
B-: 68%
C+: 64%
C: 60%
C-: 55%
D: Less than 55%, but not Life Depleted
F: Life Depleted - Round Failed